# Conditional formatting based on multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to figure out how to write a formula for Google Spreadsheet where:

> If F3 Contains Data *and* G3 is more than 0 *then* cell J3 is Highlighted in Green

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional formatting in cell J3 with the formula **=AND(ISBLANK(F3)=FALSE,G3>0)**

Step-by-step:

1. Select cell J3 and click on **Format > Conditional formatting**
2. Select the options as in the screenshot below and paste the above formula in the required field.

[image: Google Sheets - Conditional formatting]

Conditional formatting is applied if the formula results to TRUE.
This will only be the case if both the cell F3 is not be blank (= contains data) and if cell G3 is higher than 0.